# Trouble with getting materials to change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, renderer

I am writing my first game and am running into noobie errors I'm sure. Been able to work through most of them, but this one has me stumped.

I have 4 different material skins to choose from added to a series of balls. I plan to have more than that in the future as well. The code I have is working for the first 2 materials, but when I call to the 3rd or 4th, they just default to my second material.

The following code is on each of the balls under Start():

```
// Changes the material of the ball to a set type (set in the meshRenderer on each ball)
// [0] - plain, [1] - metallic, [2] - neon, [3] - pastel
MeshRenderer meshRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
meshRenderer.material = meshRenderer.materials[0];
```

When it is set to materials [0] or [1], it works properly, but when it is [2] or [3], it is defaulting to the [1] material.

The materials are set in folders:
* Assets/Resources/Materials/Plain
* Assets/Resources/Materials/Metallic
* Assets/Resources/Materials/Neon
* Assets/Resources/Materials/Pastel

An example of the naming convention is Black_plain or Blue_metallic.

I also have the materials dragged into the MeshRenderer materials array.

Any help or advice is appreciated. As I said, I am very new to this and am pretty sure the answer is probably blaringly easy. >< Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to the issue finally. Whichever one you remove the // from will change the texture to that one by pulling the material from the folder directly rather than calling to what was added to the MeshRenderer materials array. The ballName is the name of the ball's color.

```
// Changes the material of the ball to a set type (set in the meshRenderer on each ball)
// [0] - plain, [1] - metallic, [2] - neon, [3] - pastel
MeshRenderer meshRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

//meshRenderer.material = Resources.Load("Materials/Plain/" + ballName + "_plain", typeof(Material)) as Material;
//meshRenderer.material = Resources.Load("Materials/Metallic/" + ballName + "_metallic", typeof(Material)) as Material;
//meshRenderer.material = Resources.Load("Materials/Neon/" + ballName + "_neon", typeof(Material)) as Material;
meshRenderer.material = Resources.Load("Materials/Pastel/" + ballName + "_pastel", typeof(Material)) as Material;
```

Hope this might help anyone else that was having the same issue.